# override Django get_or_create

Tags: python, django, django-models, subclass, django-managers

I have a model that I overrode the `save` method for, so that the `save` method can be passed in some data and auto-fill-in a field before saving. Here is my model:

```
class AccountModel(models.Model):

    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)

    def save(self, request=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if request:
            self.account = request.session['account']
        super(AccountModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The idea is I set up a base model for objects that need to be associated with an account and then I won't have to deal with the account connections every time they come up (which is a lot).

But: I'd also like to use `get_or_create`, which saves the new objects without passing in the request. I know it is doable to not use `get_or_create` and do a `try`/`except` instead, but I'd like to know **if there is a way to override `get_or_create` and what is the proper way to do it**.

I looked at the code for the `Manager` (which I am looking at overriding) and the `get_or_create` function just calls a `QuerySet.get_or_create` function. Maybe I can write it to use other manager functions and not the `QuerySet` version of `get_or_create`?
What do y'all think?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could subclass `django.db.models.query.QuerySet` and override the `get_or_create` method there to accept your `request` keyword argument and pass it onto `save` I guess, but it isn't very pretty.

```
class AccountQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def get_or_create(...):
        ...
```

You could then add a custom manager to your `Account` model which uses this custom `QuerySet`:

```
class AccountManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return AccountQuerySet(self.model)
```

Then use this manager in your model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = AccountManager()
```

But you might find that the `try-except` method is neater after all :)

Comment: This helped me when I needed to override bulk_create().  Thanks!

Comment: This kept me from using Django internals when trying to override/overwrite/redefine `update_or_create`.

Comment: _"isn't very pretty"_? I think yours _is_ a neat solution. Without it, you need to keep a discipline of never using `get_or_create` anywhere for this particular model, which sounds dangerous to me.

Comment: looking for something similar then i found this post. even though get or create is pretty neat and sweet to use try - except might be neat in some cases.

Comment: `get_or_create` calls `create` internally, so if you override `create` directly it'll fix `get_or_create`, `update_or_create`, etc.

Comment: @Arion : for me , overriding `create`didn't work. Doing the same thing on `save` did.